# LWJGL texturing

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

```
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import  static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import  static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import  static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImageFilter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.DoubleBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import  static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWCursorPosCallback;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWKeyCallback;
import   org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;


public class test {
public static int program;
public static int vid,aid,iid,count,tid;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        glfwInit();
    long window =  glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "HI", 0 , 0);


     glfwShowWindow(window);


    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);


    GL.createCapabilities();
   TextureLoader texture = new TextureLoader(new File("D:/work/opengl2/src/opengl2/no.png"));
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        {

            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            new test().bind();


            glBindVertexArray(aid);

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iid);
            texture.bind();

            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);


            glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

          glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
            glBindVertexArray(0);



            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();
        }

    }







    //bind the data

    public void bind()
    {
        float[] vertices = {
                -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,    // Left top         ID: 0
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,   // Left bottom      ID: 1
                0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,    // Right bottom     ID: 2
                0.5f, 0.5f, 0f  // Right left       ID: 3
        };

        int[] indices =  new int[]
                {
                        0, 1, 2,
                        2, 3, 0
                };

        float[] coords = new float[]{
                0,0,
                0,1,
                1,1,
                1,0

        };

        count = indices.length;
        //create buffers
        FloatBuffer texture = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(coords.length);
        texture.put(coords);
        texture.flip();
        FloatBuffer vert = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length);
        vert.put(vertices);
        vert.flip();

        IntBuffer indic = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(indices.length);
        indic.put(indices);
        indic.flip();

        //bind the VAO
        aid = glGenVertexArrays();
        glBindVertexArray(aid);
        vid = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vid);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vert, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        tid = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tid);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);

        glBindVertexArray(0);


        iid = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iid);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indic, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


    }

}
```

Hi guys!
I am trying to texture a polygon but when I run this code it shows me a rectangle with a strange color, like when the texture coordinates are not good for the rectangle. I bind the texture coordinates to the VertexAttribArray and then I am calling it in the main game loop. I watched a lot of tutorials but no one did like I did with the indices, I am not binding the indices into an attribarray, I normally put them into a VBO and then call it before the glDrawElements. Thanks in advance!
P.S : I am new in this lwjgl chapter so take me easy :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't  really know OpenGL 2, as it seems to be what you're using. There are multiple things I'd change (as listed below), but I recommend you to switch to OpenGL 3 and newer. It's way more recent and flexible. If you need tutorials on that, I can recommend the ones made by ThinMatrix (https://www.youtube.com/user/ThinMatrix).

Since I only know OpenGL 3 and newer, what I'm telling you might not be correct, but try:

- Moving `new test().bind();` outside of your main loop
- Try unbinding your VAO **after** your index buffer has been filled with data

Comment: VAO's are in Opengl 3.0 i use a little bit of openlg2. In this code is very much opengl 11 and 15 code  . But i really do not know what am i doing wrong. Indices and vertices seems to work great. I think is just a VAO problem with binding or something else . Do you see a major problem in my code ?

Comment: You probably forgot to bind the texture. `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID)` will do the trick, but you would need to find out what's the texture id. If you only have a single texture, try using 1.